# How to integrate Chrome extension MV3 with PayPal

Tags: google-chrome-extension, paypal, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

How can I use PayPal to charge users for feature(s) in my MV3 Chrome extension?
I'm specifically looking for PayPal as Stripe isn't supported in my country.

This is the first-ever time I'm trying to charge money for anything, so I wish to do it the right way the first time.

Also, my extension is open-source, so if I could make the code in a certain way to prevent the user from bypassing the storage to enable the feature without paying, it'd be cool.

Answer (score 2):

You need a web server that provides services and payment verification if you want to prevent the user from bypassing anything.

Current versions of [the PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) require loading external JS resources, which browser extensions typically frown on. So the simplest solution, again, is going to be to have your extension direct over to a web page to handle the payment.

If you insist on processing the payment directly from your extension, the only possible way would be using a legacy HTML-only PayPal flow, most simply opening a tab to a link such as:

`https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_xclick&item_name=payment%20purpose%20goes%20here&amount=100&currency_code=USD&business=receiverofpayment@emaildomain.com`

This would not be at all secure or verifiable, other than perhaps if you were to also integrate the legacy IPN service on a server (also a bad idea).

So in summary, to do what you want to do you ought to pair a server and web page with your extension for payment processing/verification.

See the full stack example at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/ , and do API calls from your server's backend (in whatever programming environment, the node js there is just an example) for the order creation and capture. Your 2 server routes should be called from your web page, ideally using [this approval flow](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) includes a sample of error handling code for if the capture fails.

Comment: Can you give a working example for a repo with such a setup? It's easier for me to work with examples